# No puedo mostrar las imágenes de /public

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo mi back deployado en Heroku y mi front en Vercel. El proyecto es PERN stack. Tengo en el front, en la carpeta public una carpeta assets con imágenes de pokémon en formato .gif, que son las que utilizo para renderizar las cards de los pokémon. Ahora todo esto me funciona perfecto en el proyecto cuando lo inicio en mi localhost, pero ahora que lo deployé, el proyecto se deployó bien, funciona todo, el problema es que esas imágenes de los pokémon no se ven en el deploy...

```
{
img ?
  <Link className={style.img} to={`/home/${id}`}><img src={img} alt="Img not found" height="170px" /> </Link>
    :
  <Link className={style.img} to={`/home/${id}`}><img src={`/assets/pokemons/${name}.gif`} alt="Img not found" height="190px" className={style.img} /> </Link>
}
```

Este es el código con el que cargo las imágenes en la card.

Comment: pueden ser los src del proyecto deployado. a veces sucede que subes el proyecto pero el hosting interpreta encuentra la carpeta raíz como un elemento más arriba

Comment: Y como lo podria solucionar.. ? porque el proyecto de deployo perfecto tanto back, como db como front funciona todo, el tema es que no me muestra las img

Comment: comprueba que la ruta esta bien, en caso de que este bien, te recomiendo que en vez que uses una ruta de usuario, uses una ruta dentro del proyecto, con una carpeta img y que el usuario encargado de ejecutar el proyecto tenga permisos para acceder a este, también podrías enseñar si desde la consola te da algún error en especifico

Comment: @Woky88 podrías compartir el código de tu aplicación express del archivo principal? también por favor indica cual es la estructura de los archivos de ambas apps (frontend y backend) y por último por favor indicanos como se llama la imagen que quieres mostrar y en donde la tienes ubicada dentro de esa estructura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar, utilice require.context() y pude acceder y mostrar las imagenes. Gracias a todos. Dejo la solucion por si alguno tiene el mismo problema

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Y por las dudas, lee [answer].